# How to download assets on phone and use it in a react native app

Tags: react-native

I want to download images from server and use them in application.
Like many games on mobile do.
I also want that these files can not be seen in user's gallery and they can not delete it manually in React Native App

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I'm having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) package can be used to download images from server and use them in your application.

Comment: Will downloaded assets be shown in user's gallery, I don't want them to accidently or intentionally  delete them

Comment: It will not get downloaded to user's gallery